# MYSQL update from another table multiple columns

Tags: mysql

need help with an update query that its getting to long and finally time out, my table objetive(012019) for update have 1,5 millions rows and the table with the data source (january2019) its about 54k rows, both have 37 columns and i need to update 31 of them.
The structure its something like:

```
ID,X1,X2,X3,X4...X37
```

Where ID its Integer and Columns decimals

For test i tried just update one of the columns `X6` but fail.
and i need to update all of them from `X6 TO X37` so its a very long update.

i tried this:

```sql
UPDATE 201901 
JOIN(SELECT * FROM january2019) FQUERY ON 201901.ID = FQUERY.ID 
SET 201901.X6 = FQUERY.X6;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a subquery, that may be preventing it from using the indexes of the tables.

```
UPDATE 201901
JOIN january2019 AS fquery ON 201901.ID = FQUERY.ID 
SET 201901.X1 = FQUERY.X1,
    201901.X2 = FQUERY.X2,
    201901.X3 = FQUERY.X4,
    201901.X4 = FQUERY.X4,
    201901.X5 = FQUERY.X5,
    201901.X6 = FQUERY.X6,
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, well i did that query as soon you post it, but around 1 hour later still loading,  i check with SHOW PROCESSLIST; and says time: 5094 state: sending data, and that for just 1 column, any idea of how much will take?

Comment: Do both tables have an index on the `id` column?

Comment: Well that was the problem one of them had not index so finally take 2 seconds query thanks alot!